# Unable to Access Req.body (Nodejs Express)

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am new to Node.js and trying to make an API which would add a user into MongoDB database, my problem is I am Unable to access any properties of `res` & `req` in my controller. I tried searching for answer on SO but it seems the problem lies how you export the routes but the more I see the answers the more I get confused.
Here is part of my  `Server.js` file,

```
const express = require("express");
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
app.use(cors(options));
app.use(express.json());
```

This is how I am registering `Routes`,

```
readdirSync("./routes").map((r) => app.use("/", require("./routes/" + r))); //here route folder is being registered as a controller
```

Now in my `Routes/User.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const { register } = require("../controllers/user");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/register", register);
module.exports = router;
```

In `Controller/User.js`

```
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  // here is the problem, when this controller is hit, i want to send response back 
 // like res.send("user added successfully") but I am unable to access req."send" or "body"
};
```

I have Tried using `app.use(express.json());` answer on some forums but to no avail.

Comment: Your comment references both `res.send` and `req.send`, which do you mean? Only `res.send` would be correct. It would help if you show the actual code that errors and the full text of the error.

Comment: yes `res.send` in this context. Also, there is no error, I am just unable to access `send` property of `res` although if i get rid of layering and declare that route in `server.js` file itself it works it means, I am not  exporting the `route` correctly. that what i think

Comment: This feels like it's time to stop, find a "node with express and mongo" tutorial, and just run through that. There's a bunch of questionable things going on here, like those routes, that would greatly benefit from just seeing how someone more experienced did this, and following their example. This is not a niche topic, there are some excellent tutorials out there.

Comment: If there is no error, how exactly did you determine that you "can't access it" and what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I am following an example and and followed everything, also, even if i just straight up download the source code it still does not work, i think its because of different version, that why I am posting so you guys can point me in right direction.

Comment: Going directly to a multiple file and multiple level project when you don't really know the basics of Express is just not a smart way to do things.  Walk before you run.  Take the first file you show in your question and run only it.  Remove the imports of your other files.  Then, create a router in that one file.  do `app.use(router)`.  Then, create a single route on that router.  Verify that route handler works.

Comment: Then, move the router and route to a separate file and import it and verify that things work.  Then, add the controller in the same file.  Verify that works.  Then, move the controller to its own file and verify it works.  When something doesn't break, you will know exactly what broke because you will have gone from a working version to a non-working version with just a couple changes and you should know where to look for the issue.   Walk before you run.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to solve the problem by myself, so in `controller/user.js` i changed from

```
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  res.send("working");
};
```

to

```
const register = (req, res) => {
  res.send("not implemented");
};

module.exports = {
  register,
};
```

it solved my problem and now I was able to access `res` properties like `send`